# Output TestNG screenshot to Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

I'm looking for a solution to output a TestNG/Selenium screenshot in Jenkins. Ideally, when a Jenkins job runs I want to either have the images embedded into the Console Output or have a link display so the user can view the screenshot in a separate window.

Here's a function I'm using right now:

```
@AfterMethod
public void takeScreenShotOnFailure(ITestResult testResult) throws IOException {
    if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        System.out.println("Status: " + testResult.getStatus());
        System.out.println("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + 
        ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64) + "\" ></img>");
    }
}
```

The problem is that  Jenkins displays the output as plain text. I tried copying the output into an html page and it looks fine. So it appears that the way Jenkins presents the information causes Firefox/Chrome to display the html code as plaintext. Any idea how to get around this? Or is there a better way to get TestNG's takescreenshot functionality to work with Jenkins?

Answer (score 4):

You archive the screenshot using the "archive the artifacts" option in the "post build actions" of the jenkins project configuration page.To archive first u need to set the custom workspace for the project.The custom workspace should point to the root directory or the folder which is containing the folder of screenshots.Then after archiving all the screenshots will appear as links in the project page.Here "reports" will be folders containing the screenshots or any file.reports is under The "QTP" folder which is mentioned in the custom workspace.pls use slash instead of backslash in the archive the artifacts option.

**Project page:**

[image]

**using custom workspace in jenkins**

[image]

**archiving the artifacts using post build actions**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins console output can not show the images. But It shows the links as  links - you can click on it from the console output to the corresponding site.

So, your `takeScreenShotOnFailure` can be modified to move the image to a common ftp folder from the slave machine & provide the link in the console output. 
You should be able to see the image immediately.

It supports http/ftp links.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the html publisher plugin.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

Generate a basic html file with text and images, and it will show up as a clickable link on your job page.
The image will be stored together with all other build data in Jenkins.

Comment: the OP wants the results while the job is running.

Comment: This might be a viable solution, but where should be the html file be generated? If my code generates an html file and place it in the same directory as the one configured for HTML publisher, will a link appear on the build page? Or is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Just put the html file and your screenshot anywhere in the workspace of the current job.
Add the html publisher post-build step and configure it with the name and location of your html and screenshot files. The html publisher will take a copy of the files, store them on the Jenkins master, and create a link on the left hand side of the build page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: Put the screenshot and html in a dedicated subdirectory in the workspace of the current job.
Configure the html publisher plugin to copy that entire directory, and to publish the html file.